# How can I fix this rstudio error with TukeyHSD?

Tags: r, tukey

[image: Error displayed in console at bottom left]

Error code displayed above. I'm trying to get a Tukey test of smoking (which is divided into three categories of 0,1,2 (current smoker, previous smoker and non-smoker)) and body weight (in kg). However this code error keeps coming up.

Please can someone help me fix it.

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. It is important to paste as much as possible of your relevant code, error messages, etc. into the actual question, to make it easier for the community to help you.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. In order to ask a better question please read [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). Please don't post code and data as images, post them **in the question**.

Comment: `TGELabData$Smoking <- factor(TGELabData$Smoking)` might solve the problem.

Comment: Nevermind, changed the raw data to represent smoking from 0,1,2 to NS, PS and CS and it worked.

Comment: Thank you though